# still being prompted for credentials after installing credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git, github

Simple issue but I'm at a loss to debug this further. I followed the setup instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git to get my very own repository setup. I installed `git-credential-osxkeychain` and placed it like so:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    15520 Jun 11 21:43 git-credential-osxkeychain
```

If I run `git credential-osxkeychain` I get just as expected:

```
# Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

After installation, I'm prompted once, I supply my credentials expecting these to be stored in my keychain. But viewing Keychain access, I see nothing for github when I search and I'm prompted each and everytime I attempt a `git push`.

I'm running 10.7.4 mac os x with git version 1.7.7.4.

Any help on this annoying problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly you're seeing an issue because your git is slightly out of date.  I currently have git 1.7.10.4.

Comment: Excellent, this was exactly it. Updated to 1.7.10.4, it now works. Thanks so much.

Comment: I add a comment with my personal experience. It was working great with git 1.7.8.4 ... untill a few days ago when I decided to play with magit(and Emacs mode for git). Then the same issue as @wittyhandle appeared. Don't how whether magit is involved in the issue (don't think so , but you know... ) . In order to solve the case, I've been through the "Git set-up" page on github over and over. It solved nothing. And finally! I've found this post today on SO. Installing the last git (v1.7.12) solved it... Quite surprising. Thanks SO, and Bill . :-)